# Flood Fill recursion for pathfinding

Tags: python-3.x

I have only been programming for a week or two (as you will see) and I'm making a turn based strategy game.  I wanted to show the player's moveable range at the start of the turn and update as movements are made. I also needed a method for ranges assault, war fog, and path finding for AI.

After allotting of hunting I came across a flood fill example at https://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/a-star/introduction.html and attempted to modal it. most other examples were riddle with esoteric classes and methods so I started from scratch. Here is what I came up with.  I kind of know where the problems are but not sure how to correct it.

def mob_cost_calc():

```
#toymatrix is a fictional map for testing 
toymatrix = [[column for column in range(20)]for row in range(20)]


#move wieght is a fictional weighted map for testing
move_weight = [
    [3,5,2,7,3, 3,6,4,2,2, 4,2,3,4,2, 3,4,4,5,2],
    [7,6,4,9,8, 7,5,1,9,8, 7,8,6,5,4, 4,8,6,5,4],
    [9,3,8,4,6, 5,1,9,8,4, 7,3,5,6,1, 1,8,4,8,1],
    [1,9,3,7,4, 8,5,1,9,3, 8,4,0,0,7, 9,9,8,7,9],
    [4,9,6,5,5, 2,6,4,9,4, 8,7,9,8,7, 3,4,2,9,8],

    [7,5,3,8,9, 3,4,7,6,5, 1,7,6,4,6, 8,7,4,2,5],
    [6,1,2,8,3, 4,6,1,8,7, 1,3,4,7,6, 1,3,8,7,4],
    [3,4,8,2,7, 5,6,1,8,3, 4,7,6,1,3, 8,7,4,6,5],
    [1,8,3,7,4, 5,0,2,9,8, 4,3,7,5,8, 3,4,7,1,2],
    [7,3,4,6,5, 1,8,2,3,7, 0,5,6,9,8, 4,7,5,1,9],

    [3,4,8,5,9, 2,7,3,4,6, 1,1,5,5,4, 1,1,8,7,2],
    [4,6,0,8,3, 7,4,1,9,1, 8,7,4,1,1, 9,2,8,1,3],
    [4,7,5,9,5, 8,1,3,4,2, 6,1,0,7,8, 1,3,6,4,1],
    [8,7,5,6,1, 9,4,3,8,5, 1,9,1,3,8, 4,7,5,1,9],
    [2,9,3,8,4, 7,5,2,9,3, 4,8,7,1,9, 1,8,6,6,4],

    [5,7,8,1,5, 6,4,2,3,4, 4,9,3,7,5, 1,9,4,3,8],
    [7,5,2,1,8, 7,3,4,6,7, 8,5,6,2,1, 3,4,8,9,4],
    [5,7,4,9,3, 8,7,1,2,9, 8,7,3,4,5, 6,8,7,6,2],
    [1,3,8,4,7, 5,6,1,8,7, 4,3,8,9,2, 3,2,4,5,9],
    [8,7,7,2,3, 9,7,8,4,6, 1,5,4,1,7, 8,2,3,9,5]
    ]         
#map attributes              
TILE_SIZE =50


#initializing the matrix format appropriae to the given map size
    #1. max_range_matrix is a map of zeroes to store movement potential
    #2. mod_draw_matrix is for drawing reachable tiles on the screen
    #3. playerpos is the player's mobility check start position
    #4. mobility is a unit's movement attribute
max_range_matrix = [ 20*[0] for row in range(20)]
mob_draw_matrix = [ 20*[0] for row in range(20)]
playerpos = [10,10]
mobility = 6
#adds map mobility value in a a radius around the player position on a map
#of zeros
#1.1 zeros are discarded as impassable and act as a floodfill range
#note:to see this, run program and adjust window to line up the matrix.
for row in range(20):
    for column in range(20):
        if abs(playerpos[0] - column) +  abs(playerpos[1] - row) <=mobility:
            max_range_matrix[row][column] = move_weight[row][column]

#zeros flood fill origin to exclude from distance addition
max_range_matrix[playerpos[1]][playerpos[0]] = 0

#Initializing variable for flood fill recursion
    #1. nodes i and j represents a floodfill + shape mapping the area
    #2. the various check dicts swap data for flood fill recursion process
    #3. nodeC starts at player position and cycles through old open checks
    #4. close check stores processed checks for path efficiency calcs
NODEj = ((0,-1),(0,1))
NODEi = ((1,0),(-1,0))
mob_newOpenCheck_dict = {}
mob_oldOpenCheck_dict = {}
mob_closedCheck_dict = {}
nodec = playerpos 
new_openCheck_update_dict = {}


counter = 0
while True:
    if nodec != playerpos:
        for old_position, old_move_cost in mob_oldOpenCheck_dict.items():
            nodec = [old_position[0], old_position[1]]
#checking mobility cost down ,left, up, right from current nodeC position.
#1. nodes to shift mobility lookup in a cross patern
#2. storing coordinate(xy) and cumulative mobility values in new
#dictionary
#3. if cross checks overlap, it stores the lower of the two travel cost
#values
            #note: i=y and j=x. Matrix[i][j] and Position(x,y) are reverse
            for i in range(2):
                for j in range(2):
                    i_adj = nodec[1] + NODEi[i][j]
                    j_adj = nodec[0] + NODEj[i][j]
                    current_move_cost = max_range_matrix[i_adj][j_adj]
                        + old_move_cost

                    current_position = (j_adj, i_adj)

                    #testing for lowest travel cost on current tile
                    #evaluation
                    #swaping dicts to prevent self editing durring recursion 

                    #problem!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!


                    new_openCheck_update_dict = {}

                    for new_position, new_move_cost in
                    mob_newOpenCheck_dict.items():
                        if current_position != new_position:
                            new_openCheck_update_dict[current_position] = 
                            current_move_cost
                        elif current_position == new_position and 
                            current_move_cost < new_move_cost:
                            new_openCheck_update_dict[current_position] = 
                            current_move_cost

                    for current_position1, current_move_cost1 in 
                    new_openCheck_update_dict.items():
                        mob_newOpenCheck_dict[current_position1] = 
                        current_move_cost1





    else:
        #checking mobility cost down ,left, up, right from player position.
        #1. nodes shift mobility lookup in a cross patern
        #2. storing coordinate(xy) and mobility value in new open dictionary
        #note: i=y and j=x. Matrix[i][j] and Position(x,y) are reverse.
        for i in range(2):
            for j in range(2):
                i_adj = nodec[1] + NODEi[i][j]
                j_adj = nodec[0] + NODEj[i][j]
                move_cost = max_range_matrix[i_adj][j_adj]
                move_cost_pos = (j_adj, i_adj)
                mob_newOpenCheck_dict[move_cost_pos] = move_cost    

    nodec = [0,0]

    #removing impassable  area(s) from floodfill scan
        #note:cannot delete from interating object so a list is used
        #and cleaned at every pass
    del_zero_positions = []        
    for position, move_cost in mob_newOpenCheck_dict.items():
        if move_cost == 0:
            del_zero_positions.append(position)

    for position in del_zero_positions:
        del mob_newOpenCheck_dict[position]

    #dumping mobility old check into closed check
    for position, mob_cost in mob_oldOpenCheck_dict.items():
        mob_closedCheck_dict[position] = mob_cost

    #replaceing mobility old check with with new check data for next
    #floodfill pass.
    #compare with closed to make sure fronteir doesn't move backwards


    #problem!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!


    mob_oldOpenCheck_dict = {}
    new_openCheck_update_dict = {}
    for new_position, new_move_cost in mob_newOpenCheck_dict.items():
        for closed_position, closed_move_cost in       
            mob_closedCheck_dict.items():
            if new_position != closed_position:
                new_openCheck_update_dict[new_position] = new_move_cost

    for key, value in new_openCheck_update_dict.items():
        mob_closedCheck_dict[key]=value


    #clearing new check for next pass
    mob_newOpenCheck_dict = {}



    #set counter for experimentation
    if counter == 2:
        break
    else:
        counter += 1
        continue






print('map matrix')
print(toymatrix)
print('\nmax range_matrix')
print(max_range_matrix)
print('\nmob_newOpenCheck_dict')
print(mob_newOpenCheck_dict)
print('\nmob_oldOpenCheck_dict')
print(mob_oldOpenCheck_dict)
print('\nmob_closedCheck_dict')
print(mob_closedCheck_dict)
```

mob_cost_calc()

Comment: there were some obvious mistakes at the bottom that have been corrected. the thing I need to know is how to implement the   lowest value check on the tile check crossover and how to eliminate backwards cross over. the new check is not receiving the data. it works well if I don't care about tracking weighted movement.

Comment: suggest you maybe call out the particular issues you are aware of..  otherwise this feels like you're just asking for code review in which case https://codereview.stackexchange.com/  is a better home..

Comment: Sorry, I'm new.  When you're adding to a dictionary from another dictionary, how do you prevent the one you're writing from from updating existing key:values in the one you're writing to?  also, how do you do a value check to see if the dict should transfer the key:value pair in question? can these checks be done within a recursion?

Comment: after allot of hair pulling I found      "if current_position in mob_newOpenCheck_dict and current_move_cost < mob_newOpenCheck_dict[current_position]:"  to replace the iterating check. and the same form with the other problem.  I finished it and it works well thanks to all the helpful hints here.  thanks guys!!!!!

Comment: great stuff. You should add this as an answer though, ( Its ok to answer your own questions)

Answer (score 0):

replace the iterating check with

if current_position in mob_newOpenCheck_dict and 
   current_move_cost < mob_newOpenCheck_dict[current_position]: